# How to disable Backblaze's auto-renewal of the service?

Tags: backup

I wonder how to disable Backblaze's auto-renewal of the service.

The best I could find was to remove my credit card information, but then it immediately delete my backup, as shown in the screenshot below. I want my backup not to be deleted till the last day of my contract.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible.

Answer from their customer service:

> Auto-billing is a required part of our terms and agreement, so there is no way to auto-cancel. You would need to manually cancel following these steps:
>
> https://help.backblaze.com/entries/95526007-Canceling-an-Account
>
> If you forget to cancel before the auto-renewal, you can let us know and we can issue a pro-rated refund for yearly and bi-yearly licenses.

(Needless to say I deleted my Backblaze account upon learning it)

Comment: Very disappointing of them... Thanks for the information.